# Invoking `smbclient -L localhost` in Ubuntu gives: NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: linux, configuration, samba

I have Ubuntu Intrepid with Samba installed on my machine. I have a basic configuration file included below.

When I try to invoke

```
smbclient -L localhost
```

I get the error:

```
NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

This also happens when trying to invoke `smbpasswd`.

What are the possible causes of this error?

When I run both:

```
iptables -L
iptables -t nat -L
```

They are both empty.

Here is my config file (Running `testparm` reports that it's ok):

```
[global]
   workgroup = MSHOME
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   dns proxy = no
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   max log size = 1000
   syslog = 0
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   encrypt passwords = true
   passdb backend = tdbsam
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
[printers]
   comment = All Printers
   browseable = no
   path = /var/spool/samba
   printable = yes
   guest ok = no
   read only = yes
   create mask = 0700
[print$]
   comment = Printer Drivers
   path = /var/lib/samba/printers
   browseable = yes
   read only = yes
   guest ok = no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server wasn't even running.

It seems in Ubuntu 9.04, the init.d scripts are broken.

If the `/etc/default/samba` config file has:

```
RUN_MODE="inetd"
```

set, then the init.d script will fail to start `smbd`. So just set the variable to:

```
RUN_MODE="daemons"
```

or delete that file entirely, and it will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see an interface definition.  I think your issue is that the service simply isn't bound to the loopback address, so when you connect, you're rejected.

Try adding this to your [global] section of your smb.conf file:

```
interfaces = ${your-ip-address}/{your-subnet-in-dotted-quad} 127.0.0.1/255.0.0.0
```

Comment: doesn't SAMBA bind to all interfaces by default?

Comment: I'm not sure what the default behaviour is, but whether it is listening or not can be confirmed using

    lsof -ni:137

Probably as root.

I'd also check to see whether SELinux was enabled -- check your system logs (/var/log/audit/* on RH systems) to see if that is denying your connection.

Comment: I tried adding: `interfaces = eth0` and that didn't work. I've commented out hosts allow, or set it to 192.168.