# Samba + LDAP: smbclient -L localhost fails (NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)

Tags: iptables, domain, ldap, samba, workgroup

I'm following [Tuxnetworks tutorial](http://tuxnetworks.blogspot.com/2010/07/howto-samba-ldap-on-1004-lucid-short.html), at the last line of the first part and I'm getting this error:

```
sysadmin@samba:~$ sudo smbclient -L localhost
Enter root's password:
Connection to localhost failed (Error NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED)
```

I've read a few other threads where people [seem to have the same issue](https://serverfault.com/questions/29522/invoking-smbclient-l-localhost-in-ubuntu-gives-nt-status-connection-refused) but it either doesn't get resolved or their error [isn't something I'm having troubles with](https://serverfault.com/questions/29522/invoking-smbclient-l-localhost-in-ubuntu-gives-nt-status-connection-refused#answer-51297).

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1510536 
http://lists.samba.org/archive/samba/2009-March/147401.html

`testparm -s` output:

```
Processing section ...
Global parameter logon script found in service section!
...
Loaded services file OK.
```

Despite the `Global parameter...` error it still loads the config fine.

`smb.conf` file I'm using is the [one available in their tutorial](http://www.tuxnetworks.com/configs/smb.conf) with the following changes:

```
workgroup = MYDOMAIN.COM
netbios name = SAMBA
wins support = Yes
```

`sudo netstat -llptun` output:

```
...
tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:389    0.0.0.0:*    LISTEN    1317/slapd
tcp6   0    0 :::445         :::*         LISTEN    1414/smbd
tcp6   0    0 :::389         :::*         LISTEN    1317/slapd
tcp6   0    0 :::139         :::*         LISTEN    1414/smbd
...
```

Anyone have any idea of why I would be getting `NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED` when executing `smbclient -L localhost`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging by all of the ubuntu in your linked tutorials, I'm going out on a limb and guessing you're on Ubuntu.

Based on your netstat output, Samba is only binding on IPv6 and not on IPv4. This can be verified with this command:

```
smbclient -L ::1
```

To force Samba to bind to your v4 localhost, use `interfaces` to specify the IPs to bind.

Comment: when I execute `smbclient -L ::1` I'm now getting `NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE` at least it's a different error now. What IPs do I need to use in the interfaces section?

Comment: @user29600 `127.0.0.1/8` is good for testing IPv4 localhost, plus add whatever IPs you want to serve SMB on.

Comment: `interfaces = 127.0.0.1/8` didn't change anything... still getting the `NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

Comment: I must have missed something in the tutorial. I've now gotten rid of the `NT_STATUS_CONNECTION_REFUSED` all together without the `interfaces` options. Now working on `NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE` will post back later.